# How to set scope for system-assigned-identity in AAD?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

I have an Azure resource (Logic App) that uses its system-assigned identity to request a token from the Azure Active Directory. The Audience is an app-registration from the AAD. How can I attribute a scope to the system-assigned identity?

Answer (score 0):

You could set `scope` as `https://management.azure.com/.default` when using [AAD v2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc), **or** set `resource` as `https://management.azure.com/` for [AAD v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code).

The scope is used for calling [Azure Resource Manager Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/)s.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.